# SQL to Linq, having trouble in SUM and Multiple column group by with joins

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join, group-by

I want below query to be converted into linq for paging in MVC.

```
SELECT tblInvoiceMaster.InvoiceNo,
         tblCompanyMaster.CompanyId,
         tblCompanyMaster.CompanyName,
         tblInvoiceMaster.InvoiceType,
         tblInvoiceMaster.InvoiceId,
         Sum(tblInvoiceItem.Quantity * tblProductMaster.Rate)    AS TotalPrice,
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), tblInvoiceMaster.InvoiceDate, 113) AS InvoiceDate
  FROM   tblCompanyMaster
         INNER JOIN tblInvoiceMaster
                 ON tblCompanyMaster.CompanyId = tblInvoiceMaster.CompanyId
         INNER JOIN tblInvoiceItem
                 ON tblInvoiceMaster.InvoiceId = tblInvoiceItem.InvoiceId
         INNER JOIN tblProductMaster
                 ON tblProductMaster.ProductId = tblInvoiceItem.ProductId
  GROUP  BY tblInvoiceMaster.InvoiceNo,
            tblCompanyMaster.CompanyId,
            tblCompanyMaster.CompanyName,
            tblInvoiceMaster.InvoiceDate,
            tblInvoiceMaster.InvoiceId,
            tblInvoiceMaster.InvoiceType
```

Equivalent Linq Query:

```
                        (from company in DbContext.tblCompanyMasters
                        join invoice in DbContext.tblInvoiceMasters
                            on company.CompanyId equals invoice.CompanyId
                        join item in DbContext.tblInvoiceItems
                            on invoice.InvoiceId equals item.InvoiceId
                        join product in DbContext.tblProductMasters
                            on item.ProductId equals product.ProductId
                        //here I was having issue for group by columns from multiple tables
                        group new { company, invoice, item, product } by new
                        {
                            invoice.InvoiceNo,
                            invoice.InvoiceDate,
                            invoice.InvoiceId,
                            invoice.InvoiceType,
                            company.CompanyId,
                            company.CompanyName,

                        } into g
                        select new
                        {
                            g.Key.CompanyId,
                            g.Key.CompanyName,
                            g.Key.InvoiceNo,
                            g.Key.InvoiceType,
                            g.Key.InvoiceId,
                            g.Key.InvoiceDate,
                            Sum = g.Sum(o => o.item.Quantity * o.product.Rate)
                        }).ToList();
```

I am stuck in multiple column `GROUP BY` which are from different tables and doing `SUM` while performing multiplication, for example:

```
SUM(tblInvoiceItem.Quantity * tblProductMaster.Rate)
```

EDIT: Also suggested in the comment, do not use this kind of join queries in linq, instead use navigation properties for the better end result.

Comment: You don't have to write the whole query in one statement. It will be a lot more easier to read if you separate it. By the way, whenever I see people using joins in LINQ, something tells me that they either haven't designed the data model properly or haven't created the right relationships between the tables (entities). Otherwise, why would you need to join?

Comment: oh! I agree with the first half about breaking the query, I think you mean to break the query with multiple as Queryable and about second half, how can I keep all those data in one table, only one record is going to be there in company and each company can have multiple invoice and each invoice can have multiple invoice item, I would glad to know if there is any areas of improvement in this design

Comment: I'm not sure what's the actual issue you have here? any error or exception?

Comment: Where are the navigation properties?

Comment: I haven't used navigation properties, it is with linq join

Comment: @MohammedDawoodAnsari, I'm not saying that you should keep all the data in one table. That would be a horrible idea. What I'm saying is if you are using entity-framework, and I'm assuming you are because you have tagged your question with entity-framework, and you have created your tables/entities with the right relationships/associations, then you don't need to use JOINs in your LINQ queries. For example, instead of joining Company to Invoice, you should be able to do it like `company.Invoices`.

Comment: @ataravati, Thanks for your comment sir, I need to learn more to understand these things as I understand above comment theoretically but not by code, would be grateful for me if you can provide some link for the same. Thanks once again and yes I am using EF.

Comment: You really should start using navigation properties. These verbose joins are clunky, error-prone and greatly reduce the readability of your code.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, Thanks for your suggestion I will have a look on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `group` clause returns a sequence of `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` objects that contain zero or more items that match the key values for the group. Each `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` object has a `Key` property where are stored the key values:

```
//...  
group new { company, invoice } by new
{
    invoice.InvoiceNo,
    invoice.InvoiceDate,
    invoice.InvoiceId,
    invoice.InvoiceType,
    company.CompanyId,
    company.CompanyName,
} into g
select new
{
   g.Key.CompanyId,
   g.Key.CompanyName,
   g.Key.InvoiceNo,
   g.Key.InvoiceType,
   g.Key.InvoiceId,
   Sum = g.Sum(o => o.invoice.Quantity * o.company.Rate)
};
```

Comment: perfect answer, I am getting the same output now. Thank you so much. God Bless You.

Answer (score 4):

```
group new { company, invoice, product } by new
{
    invoice.InvoiceId,
    company.CompanyId
} into g
select new 
{
    Sum = g.Sum(o => o.invoice.Quantity * o.product.Rate)
}
```

And so on...

Comment: Thank you, it helped for both the things, I have updated the broken query and now when I reached to "select new" part of the query, company and invoice variables are not in the context and getting error for the same.

Comment: @MohammedDawoodAnsari just add `product` in groupping query and use it. updated answer